# Radon Nikodym Derivative for conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\mathbb{P},\mathbb{Q}$ be two equivalent probability measures on the space  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. And let $\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative ($\mathbb{Q}$ w.r.t $\mathbb{P}$) and $Y$ an integrable random variable defined on $\Omega$. Then we have

$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[Y] = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}Y\right] $$

Do we also have that
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[Y|\mathcal{G}] = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}Y|\mathcal{G}\right] $$

where $\mathcal{G}$ a sub sigma field of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: From: [tag:probability]: For basic questions about probability and the questions associated with the calculation of probability, expected value, variance, standard deviation, or similar statistical quantities. For questions about the theoretical footing of probability (especially using [tag:measure-theory]), ask under [tag:probability-theory] instead.

Comment: ah oke! I will remember

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, what we have is
$$\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[Y|\mathcal{G}] = \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}Y|\mathcal{G}\right]}{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}|\mathcal{G}\right]}. $$

In order to prove it you can use the definition of conditional expectation, i.e. show that for all $G \in \mathcal G,$
$$\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}\left[ 1_G \frac{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}Y|\mathcal{G}\right]}{\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}}\left[\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}|\mathcal{G}\right]}\right] = \mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}\left[1_G Y \right].$$